# Get table name from model yii2

Tags: yii

I want to get table name from model in yii2.

I tried to call the function below in vain :

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: update your question and add  the code where you call the function ..

Comment: `return '{{%user}}'; ` is when you are working with table prefix and its configured on db
if not, just put `return 'user';`
and to get the table name use `YourModel::tableName();`
see [TableName](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#tableName()-detail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
ModelNameGoesHere::model()->tableSchema->name;
```

Replace `ModelNameGoesHere` with your model's name.

Comment: this is for **yii 1**, for **yii2** is `ModelNameGoesHere::getTableSchema()->name;` or `ModelNameGoesHere::getTableSchema()->fullName;` which includes the schema name prefix

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I always mess up the syntax between yii1 and yii2